# SQL - merge two columns, with preference for one of them, while recording original source

Tags: sql-server, case, isnull

I have a table with two alternative sources of Payment figures. e.g.

```
ID    Source1_2004   Source1_2005   Source2_2004    Source2_2005 
 1           15004          14045           NULL           14545
 2            NULL           9004          46789            4555
 3            3334           NULL           4555            NULL
```

I need to merge these, keeping Source1 figures if they are available, but replacing with Source2 if Source1 is NULL.  I also want to make new columns saying what the source of the final Payment figure is. For example, the new table based on the above would look like this:

```
ID    Payment_2004    Payment_2005    Source_2004    Source_2005
 1           15004           14045        Source1        Source1
 2           46789            9004        Source2        Source1
 3            3334            NULL        Source1           NULL
```

I have been trying to use CASE WHEN, with IS NULL to make the new Payment columns, and seeing if the new Payment column matches Source1 or Source2 to create the new Source columns. However, I'm having trouble due to the NULLS in the data breaking the logic, and not quite giving the same result.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please do post your attempt so we can help you debug it. How can we help you if we can't see what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT ID
    , Payment_2004 = ISNULL(Source1_2004,Source2_2004)
    , Payment_2005 = ISNULL(Source1_2005,Source2_2005)
    , Source_2004 = CASE WHEN Source1_2004 Is NOT Null THEN 'Source1' 
        WHEN Source2_2004 Is NOT Null THEN 'Source2' ELSE 'No Source' END
    , Source_2005 = CASE WHEN Source1_2005 Is NOT Null THEN 'Source1' 
        WHEN Source2_2005 Is NOT Null THEN 'Source2' ELSE 'No Source' END
FROM YourTable;
```